# PHP Assigning 0 value with the value before in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a dynamic array that contains integer, it may be contained with the number or even 0. Something that I want to do is, how could if there is 0 value, it can be changed with the value before.

example :

```php
    print_r($final);

    Array
    (
      [0] => 21306000
      [1] => 50627412
      [2] => 2560227681
      [3] => 2796924085
      [4] => 1503047121
      [5] => 3801252003
      [6] => 3183996593
      [7] => 3966314112
      [8] => 5780499017
      [9] => 4885403031
      [10] => 0
      [11] => 0
    )
```

and my desire output was :

```php
    Array
    (
      [0] => 21306000
      [1] => 50627412
      [2] => 2560227681
      [3] => 2796924085
      [4] => 1503047121
      [5] => 3801252003
      [6] => 3183996593
      [7] => 3966314112
      [8] => 5780499017
      [9] => 4885403031
      [10] => 4885403031
      [11] => 4885403031
    )
```

My code was :

```
$query = $this->model_app->risampaidenganAll($kd_anggaran, $to_date, $start);
foreach($query as $res) {
    $index = $this->if_exists($res['BL'], $amount);
    if ($index < 0) {
        $amount[] = $res;
    }
    else {
        $amount[$index]['RI'] +=  $res['RI'];
    }
}
foreach ($amount as $key => $value) 
{
    $bl = substr($value['BL'], 0, 2);
    $data[$bl] = (float) $value['RI'];
}
$sum = 0;
$arr = array();
array_push($arr, $data);
$final = array_values($arr[0]);
print_r($final);

public function if_exists($bl, $total) 
{
   $result = -1;
   for($i=0; $i<sizeof($total); $i++) {
      if ($total[$i]['BL'] == $bl) {
          $result = $i;
          break;
      }
   }
   return $result;
}
```

As we can see in picture 1, 10 and 11 was 0. And it can be assigned with the value before, it was 4885403031.

Did anyone experience with these?

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: how is this array made? Can't help much knowing output without seeing input

Comment: As @treyBake suggests. It is better to fix the code that creates the array rather than try to fudge the array after it has been created. So if you show us the code you used to create the array, we can try and help you fix that

Comment: @treyBake I've been added some of my code above.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I've been added some of my code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work, but like said in the comments, this looks like some workaround and may not be the best option... Also note that the first element of the array must not be 0, or it will throw an error:

```
while (array_search(0, $array)) {
    $array[array_search(0, $array)] = $array[array_search(0, $array)-1];
}
```